# Conditional login with OpenId Connect

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid-connect

I've been reading about openid connect and doing some experiments with Keycloak.

**My question is**: Is it possible to add conditional login to an OpenId Connect server?

This is what I'm trying to do. I'm using Keycloak as an identity provider. Clients allow their users to login through my app. But I don't want anyone to access those clients; only those who have paid a subscription can access a client. If a user tries to log in, but he or she hasn't paid a subscription, Keycloak should redirect to a page where the user can buy a subscription plan.

If this is not possible with OpenId Connect, is there a way to do it with Keycloak?

Thank you

Comment: That's possible by Keycloak. Keycloak  provides a flexible way to add required action or own authenticator  to login steps.

Comment: Thank you @MuhammedYalçınKuru, I think that's what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 concerns here and it is a general pattern rather than being specific to Keycloak:

- Authenticate the user
- Whether user is authorised to use the app

The most standard approach is to use 2 sources of user data:

- Look up the user from the access token in your own data after login
- See if they have paid
- Redirect to the subscription plan page if not

My blog post on [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/) may give you some ideas.

**POSSIBLE IMPLEMENTATION**

After login, the UI can call an API endpoint to get claims for the user in the access token:

- GET /api/userclaims/current

The response can contain an object with fields (claims) from multiple data sources - not just the token. Here is a [sample claims object](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/logic/entities/claims/sampleClaims.ts) of mine.

A useful technique can be to do the claims collection when your API first receives an access token, then cache results for subsequent API calls withe the same token:

- [Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts)
- [Blog Post on Claims Caching](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)

Comment: Thank you, @GaryArcher. With these two sources of data you mention, how would I implement that without passing the responsibility to the clients? As far as I understand, once the user is logged in, the token and the rest of the fields are generated and that information is passed to the client.

Comment: Hi Miguel - this is logically an API responsibility - we wouldn't want to put it in clients as you say. See my updated answer for how I would do it.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I think this is (partly) the idea behind Required Actions in Keycloak.